# How can I read the page title of the parent page from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, xss

I have a page that calls another page(on another server) and I want that page to read the title from the parent page. Is this possible or is there some security issue with this?

Comment: I need it for an ad.  A website is running our ads in a iframe but the ad needs access to the page title to properly target. So, the page and iframe are on their server then they execute the ad script in the iframe so I need to grab the parent's title. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot communicate across servers like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to access the parent:

```
window.parent.document.title
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about it being a separate server.

Comment: does this apply to cross-server requests?  you may be incorrect

Comment: Useful information for same site.

Answer (score 0):

Call page A the caller page (with the JavaScript on it, the one requesting the title) and page B the page you want the title of.

Can you make a third page C (hosted on any server where A can access C and C can access B) which acts a go-between and servers up a JSON or XML request from the target page to the source page (where the JavaScript can call it?)? Page C could be any web app or CGI program capable of pulling down the HTML of page B and parsing it for the title, and then serving up the result in an AJAX friendly manner for page A to consume.

I suppose the usefulness of this depends on your goals and bigger-picture point of view of your project.