# How can I find the title of parent window in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can I find the title of parent window in javascript?

I use

```
 alert(window.parent.document.FormName);
```

and

```
 alert(window.parent.document.title);
```

and

```
 alert(window.parent.parent.document.title);
```

but the  result wasn't true.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139632/how-can-i-read-the-page-title-of-the-parent-page-from-an-iframe

Comment: Maybe will helpful https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/hazem/entry/accessing_parent_window_elements_from_child_window_in_javascript5?lang=en

Comment: What exactly is this window? How it is created? Where it is located? Does it even have a `parent`? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Hey have you solved your problem ???

Comment: Unfortunately no, thanks for u'r answer. I tested it. that was true. but in my code, I didn't find the result.

Comment: why ? tell me or post your code, i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for your solution

1. pageMain.html

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Parent Window</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type="text" id="data" value="23444" />
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openChildWindow();">Open Child Popup window</a>
   </body>
   <script>
   function openChildWindow() {
       window.open('page1.html','childWindow','width=400,height=400');
   }
   </script>
   </html>
   ```
2. page1.html

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Child Window</title>
   </head>
   <body onload="initializeMainDiv();">
       <div id="mainDiv"></div>
   </body>
   <script>
   function initializeMainDiv() {
      alert( window.opener.document.title )
     }
     </script>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to access the title of the `parent` window from an `iframe` which is located on another server. For security reasons it is impossible.